# How to create a tags of jQuery auto complete dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery script like bellow:

```
var availableTags ="";
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
  var Title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
  var Contact = Title+",";
  tags= $("#AutoDiv").append(Contact);      
  availableTags[tags.text()];
});
```

But my jQuery auto complete does select it as a single line of text.

How can I make a variable like bellow from .each result of jQuery

```
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
];
```

Comment: not 100% sure what you need but it looks a bit weird how you are adding tags to `var availableTags`. If you want an array of strings you should try. `var availableTags = [];` and in the loop `availableTags.push(tags.text());`

Comment: Really not clear what your specific problem is or what you are asking

Comment: how can I put values of title in availableTags variable

Comment: I want to create autocomplete tags from result of data coming from database.